# Multiple localhost domain with expo / emul

Tags: javascript, react-native, localhost, expo

I'm making a React native app with expo and android emulator. I need to fetch my local api.

I have already succeed with an api running with docker on localhost:8989 (i had to put the local expo ip http://10.0.2.2 to reach localhost)

But here, i have site1.local , site2.local and api.local running on an apache server on localhost listening port80.
My three site are working with laravel and for further option:

1. http://localhost => 404 (only localhost/oauth/token reachable (because of passport)
2. http://site1.local ; http://site2.local ; http://api.local => all route reachables

How can i fetch theses site with expo ? If i put http://10.0.2.2/oauth/token it's working, but any other not working (404 error)

I'm kinda lost :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone encounters this problem, this worked for me.

Use ngrok: `./ngrok http http://api.local`, this makes a tunnel and your local site will be reachable via https.

U will obtain an address like: https://2186-2a06-4d12-1a7f.ngrok.io

The trick was to use this address in my `.env` by overwriting `API_DOMAIN` and the magic appeared in my expo project using this address, I'm able to make some request to my API.